# Record ranking in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

For example, i have a table:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS example;
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example.etable (starttime datetime, name string,) ENGINE = MergeTree;
```

In order to apply the GROUP BY operation , I need to calculate the rank for each record, so that consecutive ordered records with the same value of the "name" field have the same rank. If the current record has a value of the name field other than the previous one, then the rank is incremented.

In MySQL this can be done with query like that:

```sql
SELECT name, starttime, 
    @prev := @curr,
    @curr := name,
    @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank
FROM example.etable,
    (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY starttime ASC;
```

Example output:

```
+------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+------+
| name | starttime           | @prev := @curr | @curr := name | rank |
+------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+------+
| s1   | 2020-05-14 15:56:46 | NULL           | s1            | 1    |
| s1   | 2020-05-14 15:56:49 | s1             | s1            | 1    |
| s1   | 2020-05-14 15:56:51 | s1             | s1            | 1    |
| s2   | 2020-05-14 15:56:53 | s1             | s2            | 2    |
| s1   | 2020-05-14 15:56:56 | s2             | s1            | 3    |
| s3   | 2020-05-14 15:56:59 | s1             | s3            | 4    |
+------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+------+
```

So, here is the question, how can I achieve this in Clickhouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculation *rank* consist of three steps:

- transform relation to arrays (groupArray)
- calculate ranks (arrayCumSum)
- transform arrays to relation (arrayJoin).

```sql
SELECT result.1 starttime, result.2 name, result.3 rank
FROM (
    SELECT 
        groupArray(starttime) starttime_arr,
        groupArray(name) name_arr,
        arrayCumSum((name, index) -> index = 1 ? 1 : (name_arr[index - 1] = name ? 0 : 1), name_arr, arrayEnumerate(name_arr)) ranks,
        arrayZip(starttime_arr, name_arr, ranks) result_array,
        arrayJoin(result_array) result
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
            /* emulate the 'example.etable'-table */
            SELECT toDateTime(test_data.1) AS starttime, test_data.2 AS name
            FROM (
                SELECT arrayJoin([
                    ('2020-05-14 15:56:46', 's1'),
                    ('2020-05-14 15:56:49', 's1'),
                    ('2020-05-14 15:56:51', 's1'),
                    ('2020-05-14 15:56:53', 's2'),
                    ('2020-05-14 15:56:56', 's1'),
                    ('2020-05-14 15:56:59', 's3')
                ]) test_data))
        ORDER BY starttime)
    )

/* result
┌───────────starttime─┬─name─┬─rank─┐
│ 2020-05-14 15:56:46 │ s1   │    1 │
│ 2020-05-14 15:56:49 │ s1   │    1 │
│ 2020-05-14 15:56:51 │ s1   │    1 │
│ 2020-05-14 15:56:53 │ s2   │    2 │
│ 2020-05-14 15:56:56 │ s1   │    3 │
│ 2020-05-14 15:56:59 │ s3   │    4 │
└─────────────────────┴──────┴──────┘
*/
```